# VB6 application works with UDP on Windows XP not Win 7

Tags: windows, vb6, udp

I developed an application with vb6 that receives message from TCP/IP and process message to XML format. And then it send out message to UDP port at 127.0.0.1. There are another application reads UDP messages.

In short explanation:

```
[ App 1 : send ] ---> TCP/IP 
---> [My App : receive and transform to XML format ] ---> Send to UDP
---> [ App 2 : read UDP ]
```

The App 1 aren't mine, some huge vendor developed and I assume it is more like my application's problem than their applications.

In the windows XP environment, all applications installed in XP machine. I had no problem for many years.

However, I upgraded my system to Windows 7. Most parts work but reading UDP in the App 2 isn't work at all.

I did test with Network Tester which I created. I was able to see XML format of message which passed to UDP port. However, App 2 isn't not reading an message at all.

I had same configuration for XP and 7. For each application, they had ini file and config file that I can copy and apply to new Windows 7 system. So I believe their configuration are exactly same.

Also, I ran all of them in Windows XP compatibility mode. But it didn't helped.

I disabled anti-virus software, firewalls and other endpoint solutions but was not successful. And I think these software aren't problem because my Network Tester was able to read UDP message.

Do you have any suggestions to check further? Is there something different in UDP from XP to 7?

Comment: check Windows Firewall isn't blocking your app in Windows 7

Comment: I am sure I disabled Firewall. I manually stopped and disabled its service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several version of application which received TCP/IP messages and pass it to UDP. I was using one of previously developed application, not latest. The lastest update solved problem. I assume that previous ones aren't developed latest version of VB6. However, the latest version developed on VB6 with latest service pack as well as Microsoft's fix on UDP problem.

If you encounter same problem, please update VB6 to latest and re-compile the project and refer Microsoft's tech support page.